# Netbeans sftp download "only new"

Tags: php, netbeans

I am working with Netbeans 7.0.1 (for PHP) and sync some files over sftp from two places.

If I download a folder on one machine, Netbeans shows me a list of all files, where only the changed files are checked for download. I do the same on my other PC but now he always checks all files for download.

How comes that Netbeans can detect file changes on one computer but not on the other? Did I mess up the config or is it a Java version problem?

Thanks for your help!

It is working with:

- Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 (Build 201107282000)
- Java: 1.6.0_11; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 11.0-b16
- System: Windows XP version 5.1 running on x86; Cp1252; de_DE (nb)

It is not working with:

- Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 (Build 201107282000)
- Java: 1.6.0_30; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 20.5-b03
- System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on x86; Cp1252; de_DE (nb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen similiar behaviour with SFTP team synchronisation in Eclipse. Sometimes what happens is when you check or download a file on the server that file gets marked by the server filesystem as modified, even though it isn't. Check the timestamps on your server files and folders and see if they change after a sync or download. I still don't know exactly what triggers this but I'm just putting it out there in case your issue is related.

Comment: I checked `stat main.php` on the controller and the folder. Only access time changes. But intresting idea. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your firewall settings? [This link](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-115176.html#113923) can be helpful.

Comment: The link talks about FTP but I am using SFTP (FTP over ssh). It is much simpler regarding ports because you just need port 22. I don't see how the firewall could interfere here, especially since file transfer is working. But thanks for the input!